# Ifilter together with lambda expression

Tags: python, lambda, generator

I would like to know how to use ifilter with lambda expression together properly!
This is my code.The purpose is to get the primes below 1000.

```
import itertools
def _odd_iter():
    n=1
    while True:
        n=n+2
        yield n

def _not_divisible(n):
    return lambda x:x%n>0

def primes():
    yield 2
    it=_odd_iter()
    while True:
        n=next(it)
        #it=itertools.ifilter(_not_divisible(n),it)   #This would work
        it=itertools.ifilter(lambda x:x%n>0,it)       #This would not work

for n in primes():
    if n<1000:
        print(n)
    else:
        break
```

But when I use lambda expression together with ifilter,the result is not as my expected,why?

Comment: *"the result is not as my expected"* - what result were you expecting, and what did you get instead?

Comment: I would like to get the primes below 1000,but it get the odd below 1000 when I replace the _not_divisible(n) with lambda expression.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]

Comment: How do you get out of the while loop in primes()?

Comment: primes() is just an generator.It will not induce endless loop.

Comment: Anyway, back to your original question, I think it may have to be with the scope of your local variable n in your lambda function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `primes()` function is missing a `yield` in the loop.

To make it work without using `_not_divisible(n)` you need to give `n` in the lambda the correct scope. The simplest way to do that is to use a default argument, which "freezes" the value of `n` each time the lambda is passed to `ifilter()`.

I've reduced the loop size to make the output more compact.

```
import itertools

def _odd_iter():
    n = 1
    while True:
        n = n + 2
        yield n

def primes():
    yield 2
    it = _odd_iter()
    while True:
        n = next(it)
        yield n
        it = itertools.ifilter(lambda x, n=n: x%n > 0, it)       

for n in primes():
    if n < 100:
        print(n)
    else:
        break
```

**output**

```
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47
53
59
61
67
71
73
79
83
89
97
```

---

Here's a minor variation on the above functions.

```
def _iter():
    yield 2
    n = 3
    while True:
        yield n
        n = n + 2

def primes():
    it = _iter()
    while True:
        n = next(it)
        yield n
        it = itertools.ifilter(lambda x, n=n: x%n, it)
```